# Delivery Note in Magento PDF

Tags: php, magento, pdf

I'm trying to add a custom note to Magento's invoice PDF documents. I'm using the Deliverynote plugin.

I am trying to add this piece of code to the invoice.php code but I'm not getting any results.

```
$noteId = Mage::registry('current_invoice')->getOrder()->getData('delivery_note_id'); 

$this->_note = Mage::getModel('deliverynote/note')->load($noteId)->getNote();
```

Here is the Github location https://github.com/drewhunter/ShipNote

I also tried doing this.

$newnote = new Dh_Deliverynote_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Note();

```
    $newnote->_initNote();
    $var = $newnote->$_note;

    $vars = serialize($var);

    $this->insertDocumentNumber(
        $page,
        Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice # ') . $vars . $invoice->getIncrementId()
    );
```

How would I insert that into the PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what actually ended up working was this. It might have worked from the original $order variable in invoice.php but I am leaving it as is since it is working.

```
   $order3 = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order->getIncrementId());

   $shipNoteId = $order3->getData('delivery_note_id');

   $note = Mage::getModel('deliverynote/note')->load($shipNoteId)->getData('note');
```

Then in adding it into the invoice pdf I created a insertNote function.

```
    $this->insertNote(
    $page,
    Mage::helper('sales')->__('USPS INSTRUCTIONS: ') . $note
    );
```

I also made a video showing how to do this in Magento. http://youtu.be/bjZ31AlmN2I